# Yii2 PJAX disable replacing actual form

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, pjax, active-form

Read this tutorial:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/

What I want to achieve is, when I submit activeform to return message from controller, like "successfully added" or validation errors to another div (rather than replacing actual form with returned result)

For example in PJAX's docs https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax there is `container` param which specifies where the result from backend will be placed.

Is it possible to disable replacing actual for with return result and get result from backend using Javascript ?